# variable can't be expression -- extending the user model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I realize that there are much more elegant ways to do this, and I will get there, but this is just hacking around trying to make it all work first. I've gotten this error:

> SyntaxError at `/accounts/profile/foobar/`
>   keyword can't be an expression (views.py, line 104)

and here is the corresponding line. Note: keyword is a string that I pass in the URL and I use it to look up the user.

```
user = User.objects.get(username=keyword)
up = UserProfile(user=user.id,
                 fullname=result['fullname'],
                 email=result['email'],
                 phone=result['phone'],
                 title=result['title'],
                 department=result['department'],
                 office=result['office'])
```

Am I not mapping the `UserProfile` object to the `User` object correctly? What's the proper way to add in a foreign key -- simply pass the object itself? Insight and wisdom appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use `up.office` instead of just `office`?

Comment: rapid copy paste and overlooked it. that's not actually the issue, but thank you for seeing that.

Comment: @Brian - are you sure that's not the issue? It really looks like it to me! Which of those two lines is line 104? (even better, change your code to have each assignment on a separate line, then we can figure out which assignment is the issue).

Comment: If the UserProfile.user is a ForeignKey, then the right thing to do is to pass the user object itself.  The error message doesn't sound like that's your problem though.

Comment: `up = UserProfile(user=user, **result)`

Comment: Wunderbar. Thanks Adam and J.F. That was it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How do I go if there is a real need to have a '.' or '_' in a keyword? I have one such requirement.

Comment: @Buchi: This isn't an appropriate place to ask questions such as that. Please click on "Ask Question" in the corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily duplicated:

```
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...   return None
... 
>>> foo(a.b=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

The error message is a bit cryptic - where's the keyword? I suspect its to do with '.' being syntax for getattr.

Comment: The "keyword" refers to the same thing the "kw" in `kwargs` refers to, and `a.b.` is an expression.

Comment: I think the keyword means the name of the keyword argument, which can't be an expression.  I.e., you can't use "a.b" or "up.office" as a keyword argument.

Comment: As J.F. Sebastian and Adam Bard pointed out, I have to simply pass the entire user object. Thanks for testing this!

Comment: JF and Adam pointed out a different problem that would have appeared /after/ fixing the "keyword can't be an expression" error. Fixing up.office is the real answer to your question title as Space / Ignacio said. Just giving credit where credit is due :)  -- EDIT: I see you said it was just a copy and paste error, but the **user** not being a user instance would raise a completely different error (a ValueError)